# Convert a byte array to a class containing a byte array in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, struct

I've got a C# function that converts a byte array to a class, given it's type:

```
IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
Marshal.Copy(data, 0, buffer, rawsize);
object result = Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, type);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
```

I use sequential structs:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public new class PacketFormat : Packet.PacketFormat { }
```

This worked fine, until I tried to convert to a struct/class containing a byte array.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public new class PacketFormat : Packet.PacketFormat
{
  public byte header;
  public byte[] data = new byte[256];
}
```

`Marshal.SizeOf(type)` returns 16, which is too low (should be 257) and causes `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to fail with the following error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I'm guessing that using a fixed array would be a solution, but can it also be done without having to resort to unsafe code?

Comment: Could you use a binary serializer/deserializer instead?

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2006/11/using-memorystream-and-binaryformatter.html

Comment: Can you give a little more background to what you are doing? If possible, using the built-in serialization classes will save you a lot of headache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for unsafe code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PacketFormat
{
  public byte header;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)] public byte[] data;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a fixed size byte array.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct PacketFormat
{
  public byte header;
  public fixed byte data[256];
}
```

Comment: My question was whether it could be done without unsafe code.